# count how many targets built successfully with make

Tags: compilation, gnu-make

I regularly (multiple times a day) build a  project with make (generated with CMake, the compiler I use is clang 5.0).

Is there a way to (semi-)automatically count the number of targets, that make tried to build and how many of them were built successfully, apart from writing a script, that parses the output of the compiler?

Comment: Using `find -newer lastmodifiedfile.c | wc --lines` isn't an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not. The existing files are deleted before each compilation for reasons I have no control over.